# Entity Framework Core - Async / Sync - DbContext

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, entity-component-system

I come to you for some advice. I'm developing a console application (server) requiring an external library.

I use Entity Framework Core. But I still have gaps regarding the concept of async / await. I have read quite a few things on it, tried quite a few things.

I set up an Entity / DAL / BLL architecture concerning the database and the ECS (Entity Component System) architecture.

I have systems that call an event (OnInitialized).
In this event, I need to load different data from database (depending on the system).

It's not possible to make several parallel queries simultaneously on same DbContext. I have only one database with multiple tables.

So should I develop interaction with the database fully sync?

Or is there a pattern to use multiple async in same time?

Comment: With a console app I'd just stick to the synchronous methods. With EF, the async versions are primarily for keeping the UI thread responsive.

Comment: As long as you don't **reuse** the same instance db context in multiple scenarios, async will never run your queries in parallel.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes but in my case, when I start the server (dotnet), this create communication with the library. Multiple client in same time can execute same command who make query. So, isn't better to use async query to don't "block" the execution of other client? In this application, I can show message / UI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework DbContext is not thread safe. So you shouldn't use DbContext concurrency. But you still can use async methods for improving perfomance in .NET Core Web API apps.

Answer (score 0):

The async/await pattern is only indirectly connected to parallelism.

I think you first need to understand exactly what is happening, when you are "await"ing a Task to return. The await-keyword is a bit misleading in my opinion. It does not really wait for the function to return, instead it starts the function that you called in a separate thread, saves the current thread state in a state-engine and causes the program execution path to return control to the caller. Once the called function is finished, that state-engine reconstructs the threadstate and continues execution.

Parallelizing Tasks is actually pretty simple. Instead of a "await"ing for a function to return, you just grab the task-objects that the functions are returning, collect them in a Collection and call Task.WaitAll(collection). After that, all task-objects will have a result-property containing their results.

Comment: So in my case (multiple clients execute some (possible) same actions in same time), regardless of the management of DbContext, it's preferable to use async?

Comment: No, I was just explaining how async await internally works.  Like AlexBlogs says, DbContext is not thead safe. Each thread (async function) must have its own instance of DBContext...

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate DbContext instance (for example using a [DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)) for each parallel query. Start the queries in parallel, then await them as needed in your processing logic.

```cs
using var dbContext1 = factory.CreateDbContext();
var queryTask1 = (from e in dbContext1.Entities select e).ToListAsync();

using var dbContext2 = factory.CreateDbContext();
var queryTask2 = (from e in dbContext2.Entities select e).ToListAsync();

var query1Results = await queryTask1;
var query2Results = await queryTask2;
```